# Getting numbers from a web page, performing calculations, pasting them into excel sheet

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, c#-4.0, html-parsing

I am working on a business application that will do financial computations based upon publicly traded companies' financial statements. Specifically, I would like to use data from pages such as [this](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:TXN&fstype=ii). Such as the number for the operating income in the first column.

My current plan is to parse the page as an htm file(if I can get it). however this is my first time attempting to write an application that interacts with the web, so I am uncertain if this is the best way to proceed. I am currently expecting to implement [this](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library. to do the parsing.

Once I have all the relevant numbers, and have done the calculations, I would like to place the results into an Excel spreadsheet. This is also something I do not know how to do.

Any advice or responses detailing how to implement this plan or how to form a better one are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For financial data regarding publicly traded companies, you probably want to use a web service, rather than parsing HTML.  [This](https://data.nasdaq.com/xml.aspx) is one example of such a webservice (though I'm not vouching for its price or reliability - I've never used it). You could create a simple console app in Visual Studio (a VSTO solution is probably better, I just don't have much experience with it) that retrieves data via the web service, and then pastes and formats it in Excel via [Excel Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.14%29.aspx). There's many posts about Excel Interop here on SO, as well as all over the web.

What you're trying to do sounds so common that I wonder if there's an existing report suite available somewhere.